# Android App not Installed Error on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to install apk. its not install and don,t throw any error. i'm using android Studio.

> It just run. but not install APK.

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".UserJobUpdateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".checking" />
        <activity android:name=".VacancyViewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Home" />
        <activity android:name=".Login_err_pop" />
        <activity android:name=".Regi" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Sharing a XML will not help solving your problem. We need the error to help you

Comment: Are you trying to install it to your phone ? Maybe you should allow unkown sources

Comment: @ Cyrille Con Morales. i'm trying mobile phone. but i allow unknown source.. 
apk successfully ran up to 1 hour ago

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira i have 7 xml file. apk successfully ran up to 1 hour ago

Comment: try to build APK from Build menu and install that on your device and make sure you are selecting the correct target device.

Comment: @SathishkumarG why are you not posting the error you are getting? I just told you that with XML only we can't help you.

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira because i'm not getting any error.

Comment: Have you changed your Run Configuration?

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira i,m not change any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app build.gradle and change package name, save and make "Clean Project", then "Rebuild Project" from "Build" drop down list. Maybe in your phone there already installed app with package "com.myapp.app". Write if that solved your problem.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.changethis"
```